# Django: <view_name> takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, forms, python-2.7, django-views

My application has a form which redirects to another form based on a condition (The first form is `EvangelizedForm`, and the second conditional form is `SocialAccountsForm`)

```
def fillform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EvangelizedForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=True)
    .
    .
    .
            return redirection(request, first_name, last_name, email, other_social_accounts)
```

The view `fillform` is the view which handles the processing of the first form. On successful submission of the form, it redirects to the `redirection` view:

```
def redirection(request, first_name, last_name, email, other_social_accounts):
    if other_social_accounts == 'Yes':
        return yes_social(request, first_name, last_name, email)
```

Based on the value of the `other_social_accounts` form field in my original post, the control of the program is transferred to the `yes_social` view:

```
def yes_social(request, first_name, last_name, email):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SocialAccountsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=True)
            obj.first_name = first_name
            obj.last_name = last_name
            obj.email = email
            obj.save()
        else:
            form.errors
    else:
        form = SocialAccountsForm()

    context = RequestContext(request,
                                {'request': request, 'form': form})

    return render_to_response('rango/yes_social.html', context_instance = context)
```

yes_social.html

```
<form id="evangelized_form" method="post">
           <!-- NAME: <input type = "text" name = "name" value = "{{user.get_full_name}}"><br>    -->
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <div id = "err">{{ field.errors }}</div>
                <b>{{ field.help_text }}</b><br>
                {{ field }}<br><br>
            {% endfor %}

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

Basically, I want to store the values of `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` form fields taken from the first form along with the data submitted from the second form into the database. Hence the code:

```
if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=True)
            obj.first_name = first_name
            obj.last_name = last_name
            obj.email = email
            obj.save()
```

However, on submitting the second form, I get the following error:

```
yes_social() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

Now, I do realize that on submission of the second form, variables `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` are not passed into the view, and hence it raises the above mentioned error.

What changes can I make in my code so as to store the values of the `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` taken from the first form and store it in the database with values submitted from the second form?

EDIT 1:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
        url(r'^fillform/$', views.fillform, name='fillform'),
        url(r'^redirection/$', views.redirection, name='redirection'),
        url(r'^yes_social/$', views.yes_social, name='yes_social'),)
```

Comment: could you post your urls as well?

Comment: @RogerFederer Done. Do check the updated post.

Comment: you are not sending any parameters in the url?

Comment: @RogerFederer I don't think i know how to in my case.

Comment: i think you have to remove your arguments and have only the request in your views. can you try that and see?

Comment: @RogerFederer The reason why I passed those arguments in the first place is because I want the values of `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` in the `yes_social` view. If I don't pass them in my view, how can I possible access those values?

Comment: They're in request.POST, just like all the other form values.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Those three values are taken from the `EvangelizedForm`. The `request.POST` would contain values from the `SocialAccountsForm`, right? I need a way to pass in the form field values from the first form into the `yes_social` view, which handles the processing of the `SocialAccountsForm`